# Tortoise won't connect to subversion server

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, visualsvn-server

I'm trying to setup my home server with a Subversion repo on it (after some changes).

I uninstalled-reinstalled VisualSVN Server on the Windows Server 2003 server box and the address (i.e. URL) to the repo is `https://server.network.local/svn/`.

I can browse via IE to that address, and get the repository list (I do have to click past the certificate error though), but when I point tortoise to it as well, I get

```
OPTIONS of 'https://server.network.local/svn': Could not resolve hostname
'server.network.local': No such host is known.
(https://server.network.local)
```

I can ping and tracert to the server no problem though, so I'm not sure what the deal is.

Comment: Where is 'server.house.local' coming from?

Comment: @outis: typo. My actual server and network name are kinda dorky... I'm obfuscating.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting the error on svn client "XML parse error at line 1 no element found" when accessing VisualSVN Server?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541520/why-am-i-getting-the-error-on-svn-client-xml-parse-error-at-line-1-no-element-f)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I had the same problem, as far as I can tell you can’t go straight to the SVN folder you need to include a repository file name in the path example:

https://server.network.local:8443/svn/MyNewRepository

Hope that helps

Comment: seemed too simple, so I tried everything else first... my forehead hurts and my desk is ruined... but thanks :)

Comment: NP, glad I could help. Cheers

Comment: @Anthony - I have a related issue. Please help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27975987/cannot-connect-to-local-svn-server.

Answer (score 2):

You have to clear your local DNS cache (and if you have a DNS on your LAN, you'll also have to do that with that DNS cache).

Answer (score 2):

There is a [note at the very bottom of the VisualSVN Server Getting Started guide](http://www.visualsvn.com/server/getting-started/#ctl00_ctl00_ctl00_Content_Content_Content_BreakoutControl1) and it answers the question. The note reads:

> Unlike web browsers, Subversion clients are unable to access the
>   content of the Repositories node in the VisualSVN Server Manager. In
>   other words, you are unable to access https://svn.example.com/svn/ URL
>   using Subversion clients such as TortoiseSVN or svn.exe.

I.e. Subversion client can access a repository but the URL `https://server.network.local/svn/` points not to a repository, but to a repository root collection which you can view only with a web browser.

I also want to note that the error stated in the question can be different with newer Subversion clients. It can be:

```
XML parse error at line 1 no element found
```

Answer (score 1):

You might want to make your link 'https://server.network.local:8443/svn' and see if that makes a difference. I have that port on a tortise installation that I use.

Rick Strahl has a pretty [good article](http://www.west-wind.com/presentations/subversion/) on how to setup and run VisualSVN.

Hope this works for you.

Comment: ITYM https://server.network.local:8443/svn ... port generally goes after the server, not at end of URL :-)

Comment: The article you refer to describes setting up subversion on the local machine. I've setup subversion on the server and it works fine (I can connect via tortoise on that machine). The problem is in connecting from other machines on the network.

Comment: You might want to read this one also. http://www.west-wind.com/Weblog/posts/480534.aspx - Connecting to Subversion Source Control Repository over HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm. "Could not resolve hostname" is one layer below SSL, repositories and such. My bet is it's the (personal) firewall not letting Tortoise through.

Answer (score 0):

It's possible TSVN isn't happy with a bad SSL certificate, so you'll need to make it good (I assume it's self-signed, so you'll need to manually add the cert into the correct certificate store in Windows).

Before you go ahead and do this, what happens if you point TSVN to a non-secure version (i.e., http://) of the site? Is it happy then? If it is then it's definately pointing to SSL problems.

Answer (score 0):

Set the proxy setting of the SVN. Just right click and Tortoise SVN and setting and add the proxy setting. It may work for you.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is regarding DNS Server...

See if it gives error like this https://server.xxx.com:435/svn

if you replace server.xxx.com with the appropriate ip (mean ip of svn server computer)

it works..

so just make a AAAA record in forward lookup zone and make PTR in reverse lookup zone and problem is resolved.