# Cannot connect to local svn server

Tags: windows, svn, visualsvn-server

I am using VisualSVN Server 3.0.1 and TortoiseSVN 1.8. Using VisualSVN Server Manager, I made a repository called "lottery" in my C:\ drive. I started all the VisualSVN Server's services on the machine. I checked VisualSVN Server's HTTP service is running and VDFS service is running. I also made two users harry and sally with password 1234 using VisualSVN Server Manager. I made a directory C:\workdirs. In that, there are two folders harry and sally for my users. When I navigate into harry's folder and run my svn command, I get an error. Please help me to resolve it.

```
C:\workdirs\harry>svn co --username harry --password 1234 https://james/svn/lottery/
```

That url is copy pasted exactly from VisualSVN Server Manager. I get the error -

```
C:\workdirs\harry>svn co --username harry --password 1234 https://james/svn/lottery/
svn: E731001: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://james/svn/lottery'
svn: E731001: No such host is known.
```

**Solutions I tried -**

[Tortoise won't connect to subversion server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760900/tortoise-wont-connect-to-subversion-server)

> Apparently, you can’t go straight to the SVN folder you need to
>   include a repository file name in the path.

So, I tried to use the url with port and the repo folder name to see if it helps `svn co --username harry --password 1234 https://james:443/svn/lottery/` Btw, james is the name of the svn server i saw in the visual svn server properties.

The resulting error is -

```
svn: E731004: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 
'https://james/svn/lottery'
svn: E731004: The requested name is valid, but no data 
of the requested type was found.
```

**Next**, I tried to use http instead of https and got the same error.

**Next**, I tried to use the url like this `https://localhost/james:443/svn/lottery/`

I got the error -

```
Error validating server certificate for 'https://localhost:443':
 - The certificate is not issued by a trusted authority. Use the
   fingerprint to validate the certificate manually!
 - The certificate hostname does not match.
Certificate information:
 - Hostname: steam
 - Valid: from sometime in 2014 GMT until sometime in 2020 GMT
 - Issuer:
 - Fingerprint: 6a:7b:8c:....
(R)eject, accept (t)emporarily or accept (p)ermanently? p
svn: E175013: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 
'https://localhost/james:443/svn/lottery'
svn: E175013: Access to '/james:443/svn/lottery' forbidden
```

Finally, I thought of using my computer's IP address as mentioned in the link I gave. I don't know what the IP is, but I tried using `localhost` instead and it worked !!!

```
C:\workdirs\harry>svn co --username 
harry --password 1234 https://localhost/svn/lottery/
Checked out revision 0.
```

Comment: I just don't get it ! What is with all these people downvoting without providing a reason ? Do I need make the question clearer ? Google more ? Delete the question ? What ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This worked for me -

```
svn co --username harry --password 1234 https://localhost/svn/lottery/
```

I did not have to add a port number after localhost. It works, but I don't know what happened. Btw, make sure that your Visual SVN windows services are running before you run this command.

Answer (score 2):

Your local DNS is unaware about that "james" hostname represents your computer therefore you get the `No such host is known` error. If you work with VisualSVN Server alone, you could add a reference that "james" is your computer's name to your `hosts` file.

Otherwise, contact your network administrator and ask about what is your computer's hostname on your LAN.

Answer (score 2):

Go to your project folder Right Click  go to your tortiseSvn --> Relocate --> change your svn repository url
[image]